# Create a bar chart showing percentage of users (by Unit Group) that access via A or B or either in excel 365

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel spreadsheet that provides username, UnitGrp, AccessA (1 for yes, blank for no), AccessB (1 for yes, blank for no).

I want to create a bar chart that shows the percentage of users from each Unit Group that use AccessA, AccessB, and those who use both.

Comment: Could you provide a sample file or screenshot about this problem?